# How can I mine Monero or other altcoins using Azure Cloud Services?

Tags: cloud-mining, cryptonote, monero

Is there any way by which I can mine Monero or other altcoins using Azure Cloud Services.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - you can run [cpuminer-multi](https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=841401) on Azure or AWS, and it will CPU mine. You will need to find a pool to mine with.

Alternatively, if you want to solo mine, then you merely need to run a full Monero node, and from within `bitmonerod` you use the `start_mining` command. Details on the options you can pass to that command are available via the `help` command within `bitmonerod`.

Answer (score -2):

With the new N-Series VMs, you can now mine more:
https://medium.com/@benthompson2001/mining-bitcoin-other-altcoins-with-azure-n-series-gpu-virtual-machines-e8591895baba#.67rl6apt1